# How to decode config file using dotenv?

Tags: node.js, encoding

I am using dotenv package and encode .env file. How I can decode to get all the env variables? This is how I am reading file and encoding?

```
var dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path: filename, encoding: 'base64'});
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dotenv` package loads your environment variables into `process.env`, so you can access them there.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I can access them through the process.env. But I am encoding the .env file and I want to decode the parsed object.

Comment: I think it's a bug with `dotenv`. I've created a fix at https://github.com/d4nyll/dotenv. You can use that until I fix the [PR](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/pull/243)

Comment: @PR-d4nyll - I am using forked branch and I am still not clear how I can decode `dotenv.parsed`. Thanks

Comment: If you use the forked branch, you should get the environment variable at `process.env`, assuming your whole file is base64-encoded. I have to do more testing with my fork, but won't have time for the next few days.